# Maintain activity in onPause state at the time of screen lock?

Tags: android

When user press the screen lock currently running activity is going to onDestroy state.How to prevent this ? When Screen lock is activated I need to maintain my activity in the onPause state only?

Note:
For the normal activity when I press the screen lock button it goes to the onPause state only.. But the activity which is used to capture the video that only goes to the onDestroy state

Comment: do you mean by screen-lock the Hardware Button on a device to toggle the screeen on/off?

Comment: yes. When we press screen-lock hardware button

Answer (score 0):

You cannot kind of "choose" what the system does to your activity. If the system decides to destroy it, it will call 'onDestroy' no matter what. Only in some corner-cases you can tell the system, what it *should* do (in example don't destroy on Orientation-change). If you don't want to get killed you should aquire a [Wake Lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html).

Comment: In that activity I have captured the video frames from camera. For the normal activity when I press the screen lock button it goes to the onPause state only.. But the activity which is used to capture the video that only goes to the onDestroy state

Answer (score 0):

you can save your instance using onRestoreInstanceState() and onSavedInstanceState()